# (JAVA) I need to convert this (actually using foreach) using to streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to convert this code using streams but I don't know how to do it.

```
        List<String> lines = Files2.linesFromFile(ruta);
        List<List<String>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String line : lines) {
            List<String> aux = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String element : line.split(",")) {
                aux.add(element);
            }
            res.add(aux);
        }
```

If I show the content of res I got:

```
[[ejercicios, practica, propuesta], [cadena, recomendar, definir], [elemento, implementar, sol], [ala, map, public, static]]
```

The content of lines is:

```
[ejercicios,practica,propuesta, cadena,recomendar,definir, elemento,implementar,sol, ala,map,public,static]
```

And I need to get the same output using stream, can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And which part of this are you struggling with? Have you tried anything yet, and in which way did it not work as expected?

Comment: @HadiJ actually, to get the same result (a list of lists) `map` is enough, no need for `flatMap`.

Comment: @alevidals do you already know [`Pattern.splitAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream(java.lang.CharSequence))? With this, you can avoid the intermediate array that is the result of `String.split`.

Answer (score 1):

Using **@Hulk**'s suggestion for `Pattern.splitAsStream`, you can replace your whole `for...loop` with:

```
res = lines.stream().map(l -> Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(l).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`res` value is:

```
[[ejercicios, practica, propuesta], [cadena, recomendar, definir], [elemento, implementar, sol]]
```

If you want to "flatten" you List of Lists of Strings (`List<List<String>> res`) and make it just one List of Strings (`List<String>`)

you can use `flatMap` as:

```
List<String res = lines.stream().flatMap(l -> Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(l))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or even better as **@user16320675**
suggested:

```
res = lines.stream().flatMap(Pattern.compile(",")::splitAsStream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this outputs:

```
[ejercicios, practica, propuesta, cadena, recomendar, definir, elemento, implementar, sol]
```

Comment: Note that `l -> Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(l)` unnecessarily repeats the `Pattern.compile(",")` operation for every line, in contrast to `Pattern.compile(",")::splitAsStream` which does this only once for the entire operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Stream::map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) to transform each line and [Stream::collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) to create a new list from the stream.

Replacement for your code would be:

```
List<List<String>> res = lines.stream()
  .map(line -> {
    List<String> aux = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String element : line.split(",")) {
      aux.add(element);
    }
    return aux;
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But we can simplify it by using [Arrays::asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) to create `List<String>` from `String[]` without writing the for loop.

```
List<List<String>> res = lines.stream()
  .map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(",")))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Note that the inner lists have different mutability semantics here vs OP's original. This may or may not be important.